# Under what conditions is it true that if $f(x) \sim g(x)$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$, then $f'(x) \sim g'(x)$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics

So we say that two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ of a real variable are asymptotic to each other as $x \rightarrow x_0$ ($x_0$ need not be finite) if

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =1,$$

and in that case we write $f(x) \sim g(x)$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$. It is also not true generally that if $f(x) \sim g(x)$, then $f'(x) \sim g'(x)$. To see this, consider the cases $f(x) = x + \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = x$. In this cases it is true that $x + \sin(x) \sim x$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, yet it is not true $1 + \cos(x) \sim 1$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ (in fact the latter limit does not even exist).

My question is, under what conditions on $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ can we say that it is true that if $f(x) \sim g(x)$, then $f'(x) \sim g'(x)$ as $x \rightarrow x_0$.

Comment: How familiar are you with l'Hopital? I suggest you carefully read the statement of that theorem.

Comment: Yes, but L'Hopital requires the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) / g(x)$ to be undefined, no? In this case it is very well defined and in fact it equals $1$.

Comment: No. It is very much used to _find_ that limit, _especially_ when it's defined. But you're right, it does require it to be of indeterminate form (either $\frac00$ or $\frac\infty\infty$). So that may be too big of a constraint for you. However, in those indeterminate cases, it tells you exactly when your property holds, namely when both limits exist they must be equal.

Comment: You are right, I mispoke. I meant that $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f}{g} = \frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\pm \infty}{\pm \infty}$, clearly the limit must exist.I should have said "indeterminate form" instead of "undefined".

Comment: I do not think de l'Hospital statement can help here. In de l'Hospital we need to assume the limit of the ratios of the derivatives exists finite. Here we need the converse. We need to assume the limit of the two functions is one and from that + some extra assumptions conclude that $f'(x) \sim g'(x)$.

Comment: @SonGohan Exactly. The question is what are these extra assumptions.

Comment: Because the question is tagged "complex analysis", does that mean you want to assume $f$ and $g$ are analytic?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Indeed, for my purposes at least, this assumption is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume $f$ and $g$ are analytic near $0$ (replacing $x$ by $x - x_{0}$ if $x_{0}$ is finite), we may expand in power series
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= a_{m}x^{m} + a_{m+1}x^{m+1} + \cdots
  = \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} a_{k}x^{k}, \\
  g(x) &= b_{n}x^{n} + b_{n+1}x^{n+1} + \cdots
  = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} b_{k}x^{k},
\end{align*}
with $a_{m}$ and $b_{n}$ non-zero. Consequently, $f \sim g$ if and only if $m = n$ and $a_{m} = b_{m}$, i.e., the power series have the same first non-vanishing term.

Termwise differentiation gives
\begin{align*}
  f'(x) &= ma_{m}x^{m-1} + (m + 1)a_{m+1}x^{m} + \cdots
  = \sum_{k=m-1}^{\infty} (k + 1)a_{k+1}x^{k}, \\
  g'(x) &= mb_{m}x^{m-1} + (m + 1)b_{m+1}x^{m} + \cdots
  = \sum_{k=m-1}^{\infty} (k + 1)b_{k+1}x^{k}.
\end{align*}

If $m = 0$, i.e., $f(0) = g(0) \neq 0$, then $f' \sim g'$ if and only if $f$ and $g$ have the same first *non-constant* term, i.e., $f - f(0) \sim g - g(0)$.

If $m > 0$, i.e., $f$ and $g$ vanish to the same finite order at $0$, then $f' \sim g'$ is automatic since
\begin{align*}
  f'(x) &= ma_{m}x^{m-1}\bigl[1 + \frac{(m + 1)a_{m+1}}{ma_{m}} x + \cdots\bigr], \\
  g'(x) &= ma_{m}x^{m-1}\bigl[1 + \frac{(m + 1)b_{m+1}}{ma_{m}} x + \cdots\bigr],
\end{align*}
whose ratio has limit $1$ at $0$.

Modifications for the case $x_{0} = \infty$ are straightforward.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the formal proof of what I was thinking in my "probably so much that the functions end up to be the same, at least in that neighborhood and at least for the first-order expansion" (if they are analytic, of course). :)

Comment: +1 for your good answer, incidentally :)

Answer (score 5):

This is not a complete answer, but I fear the extra assumptions need to be too strong to be able to conclude something of this kind *at this level of generality*.

Indeed, if you know a bit of set theory, the asymptotic equivalence is an *equivalence relation*, and as such, it may be seen as a particular "equality" between functions, that tries to put together all of them in specific classes: like as if we take a great magnifying glass and we focus our attention really close to a particular point. In a nutshell, I may have a very monster function of which I may not be able to study its graph globally, so I try to use asymptotic equivalences to try to reduce, at least locally, the function to an easier one to be able to see its behaviour close to a point. For example, take $$f(x)=\sin(\log(1 + \sinh(e^{\arctan(x^3)}-1))) $$ which is asymptotically equivalent for $x \rightarrow 0$ to $$g(x)= x^3$$

But then, to be able to say their derivatives are also asymptotically equivalent for $x \rightarrow 0$, I think one must add a **very restrictive** assumption on the behavior of the functions in the neighborhood of zero, probably so much that the functions end up to be the same, at least in that neighborhood and at least for the first-order expansion around that specific point (but I do not have a proof of this, it is just my intuition).

Indeed, asymptotic calculus is not compatible with derivatives: your example is nice, as it is the following: $$f(x)=1+2x\sim_01\sim_0g(x)=1+x,$$ but $$f'(x)=2\nsim_0g'(x)=1$$